# Fire a jquery event in an iframe, run a callback in parent window

Tags: jquery, events, iframe

I can fire an event in the scope of the parent window from an iframe and listen, but I can't fire an event from the iframe in the scope of the iframe and listen for it in parent windows.. For example, in the parent window, I have an iframe and some jquery code to listen for events fired in it's body

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="/vf-install.php" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
jQuery('#myframe').contents().find("body").on('foo',function(){
    alert('foo');
});
```

In the iframe I fire an event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery("body").trigger("foo");</script>
```

I do not get my event triggered. As a side note I can trigger an event in the parent window from the iframe like this:

```
parent.jQuery("body").trigger("foo");
```

That is unacceptable to me though. The reasoning is the vf-install.php that is being included via iframe is an installer for my program. I am writing a regression test with qUnit that includes my installer in an iframe, clicks the install button, and then when the installer is done (an event is fired) the test will make an assertion. So therefore the only time it's included via iframe is while under test. Actual users call the page directly and I don't want it firing events on a parent window that is not there.

Also as a side note I tried attaching the event listener to the iframe's body when the load() even is called in case this is a "live query" related issue (events aren't binded after ajax alters the page):

```
jQuery('#myframe').load(function(){
    // attach the event listener like above
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you write a generic handler for pushing the events?

```
function triggerEvent(eventName) {
if(underTest == true) {
parent.jQuery("body").trigger(eventName);
}
else {
    jQuery("body").trigger(eventName);
}
```

Then you can just call the triggerEvent method in your code, and have your tests set the 'underTest' variable to true, or instead of having a global var, inspect to see if your test harness is present?

This solution doesn't feel overly pretty, but it might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bind function:

```
jQuery("#yourFrameID").bind("load", function() {
    var res = jQuery(this).contents().find('body').html().toString();
    //do something with the response
});
```